# Sequential message processing in JBOSS EAP 7

Tags: jboss, jboss-eap-7

I deployed my message driven beans in **JBoss** and my queues are in **IBM web sphere**. I am using resource adapter to consume messages from IBM queues.

If i push 100 messages in queue, application server J boss  executing parallel those messages.

But i want to execute sequentially one by one message.

Is there any configuration i need to change. Please help.
below i mentioned IBM application server vs JBoss application server processing.

### IBM application server processing model

Message 1 processing started
.
.
.
Message 1 processing completed

Message 2 processing started
.
.
.
.Message 2 processing completed

### JBOSS EAP & application server processing model

Message 1 processing started

Message 2 processing started

Message 1    processing completed

Message 2 processing completed

Answer (score 0):

you need to change pool settings to get sequential processing. refer below link for more info.
https://developer.jboss.org/thread/242170